# Photo info on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm picking photos from the photo albums on iPhone 4 with the help of **UIImagePickerController**. One question:

- I would like to verify the origin of the photo the user picked. Specifically speaking, I want to know that weather this photo was taken right by this iPhone 4, or was imported or downloaded from elsewhere. **Where can I get this set of information?** The corresponding NSDictionary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is extracting EXIF info from the picture and check the camera-model.

You will never be sure that the picture is taken from THIS iPhone but chances are good :-)

Check this post : [How to get EXIF data from my jpegs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564332/how-to-get-exif-data-from-my-jpegs)